# Create an Image with Halo Particles

Tags: particles, light

How would you make this?

[image: Halo 4 loading screen]

So I want to know is how you make a final image with particles, I've tried using the halo material in blender render and that didn't work, I've also tried using particles systems, once again didn't work. So is there some other way that I create an image with particles?

Comment: Well are you asking an architect "how do I build this ?" while showing him a picture of a stadium ? First you need a clean model, after that the work goes into the materials settings: you can make the glowing edges with the help of a fresnel. The light rays means volume scatter and about the sparkles maybe they are due to a bump map ?

Comment: There's a Training on exactly this topic: http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/shop/611-point-density-magical-fx.html

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific, add more details explaining how did you try to do it, so it didn't work. Add screen shots of the related panels in your project, and attach your .blend file.

Answer (score 0):

**Texture and Halo with Blender Internal Render**

Image Credit http://blackzonex.deviantart.com/art/UNSC-Wallpaper-4K-488820951

[image]

Click on image above to see more detail.

- This a quick summary.   This is not a tutorial on every step.  Neither discussion of optimization nor aesthetics.
- Texture above used. Plane was used.  No other mesh model.  Better/Different results are left as a task for the OP.
- For some readers Blender Internal Render and Halos have fallen from 3D Grace.
- This is just one alternative and may be a simple one.
- The texture was processed in GIMP to Black and White . Colors Posterize 2 levels. Transparency Added. Light Blue Color added quickly on the sides.  You may color differently or use different artwork.  Image visible above. 3 minutes after practice.  Name and location of file noted for use below.  The texture is used for location and color of particles.
- Plane in edit mode was scaled 16:9 to match texture above. Plane UV Mapped.  UV Map used below twice.  Material Slot Added. Texture Slot Added. Material is Halo type so that size of Halo used below can be changed.  Texture Added and the image above selected.
- Plane has a Particle System.  Halo.  Large panel value for particles. Only the non transparent areas will have visual particles.
- Plane, Particle System, Texture Panel Selected. That selection order is required. Texture above is chosen, Influence Panel, is set to affect particle Density.  See image.

[image]

More emphasis on values in panels. Image above.